# How to add blacklist IPs in Apache kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am sending some filebeat data to kafka. What I want is that kafka may only take data of specified IPs. Can anyone tell how can I configure kafka for particular IPs I configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way would probably be to implement [Access Control Lists (ACLs)](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authorization.html). That way if your filebeat process moves servers you don't have to arbitrarily change the accepted IP list on the Kafka machines.

However, if you actually want to create an accept-list of IPs, this isn't a Kafka feature but something you'd implement at the networking layer on your Kafka machine, with a rule to accept traffic from certain hosts to the Kafka port. For example, I found this [`iptables` guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands#allowing-incoming-ssh-from-specific-ip-address-or-subnet) which shows how to accept traffic for a given service (SSH in the example, but you could amend it to Kafka) only from a particular IP.

Comment: Thank you! It resolved my problem.